# Biot-savart's Law and mass of an electon

Tags: mass, electrons

One of the my questions is that in Physics lab we use the Biot-Savart law to derive the equation to get Mass of Electron.

$B=(8\mu_0NI)/(\sqrt{125}\cdot a)$

I started by trying to integrate both sides of the Biot-Savart law and I almost get the same equation as above except for the square root of 125.  Where does this come from? Any advice on other ways to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? To derive the field using the Biot-Savart law we need to know what the geometry of the current carrying medium is. Presumably the factor of $\sqrt{125}/a$ arises from the geometry.